# Program crash while using if statement inside a for loop

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, codeblocks

I am trying to give a shot at Project Euler problem 3 until codeblocks or whatever caused it `pissed` me off. This is my code, What is wrong with it? I guess more of a bug?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x=0;

    for(int y=0;y<=10;y++)
    {
        if(13195%x==0)
        {
            cout<<"I don't know why the program crashes!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for blaming Codeblocks for your bug; *"A poor workman blames his tools."*

Comment: Sorry, It was frustrating as I had tried for almost about an hour :/
and its ends up being a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a 0 as the second operand while doing `/` or `%`. What you're essentially saying is "Hey divide by 0 and give me the remainder."  Please see the following:

[Can't Mod Zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370154/cant-mod-zero)

Answer (score 2):

Modulus operator divides it by zero and next finds the remainder, thus you will get divide by zero error

Answer (score 1):

x must not be equal to 0 otherwise division by zero.

Just think how many zeroes in 13195?

Answer (score 0):

`x = 0`. Dividing a number with zero will crash your code. Make sure `x` is not `0` before `13195 % x`.

Answer (score 0):

The operation `A modulo B` is defined as: the remainder of the division of A by B.
In your code, you have B=0 which means you are trying to divide by zero.