# Program crashes when `if (variable % 2 == 0)`

Tags: c, crash, undefined-behavior, modulo, perfect-numbers

I'm writing a program that finds *perfect numbers*. Having read about these *perfect numbers* I came across a list of them: [List of perfect numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_perfect_numbers).  At the moment the output is:

```
28         // perfect
496        // perfect
8128       // perfect
130816     // not perfect
2096128    // not perfect
33550336   // perfect
```

I decided to create array and put it with numbers, which divide the number wholly (without the rest). So I will be able to verify if it is a *perfect* number or not by adding all elements of the array. But app crashes and I cannot understand why:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long number;
    unsigned long arr2[100] = {0};
    int k = 0;

    for ( number = 0; number <= 130816; number++ )
        if ( 130816 % number == 0 )
            arr2[k++] = number;

    for ( k = 0; k < 100; k++ )
        printf("%lu", arr2[k]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370154/cant-mod-zero

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing modulus `zero` here:

```
if ( 130816 % number == 0 )
```

which is undefined behavior. If you start your for loop at `1` instead it should fix that issue. However, since `N % 1 == 0` for all `N`, you probably need to start at `2`.

From the [`C99`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) standard, `6.5.5 /5` (unchanged in `C11`):

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the
>   second; the result of the % operator is the remainder. In both operations, if the value of
>   the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @paxdiablo You are right, I forgot to remove that statement, I amended my answer.

Comment: And a +1 for that :-) I also added the C11 stuff since that's now the "current" standard. And, actually, I think you may want to start at 2, not 1. `N%1` is zero for all `N`.

Answer (score 2):

You are dividing by zero when number=0;

`138816 % number` involves division and a remainder.