# Loop with modulus gives me an error

Tags: c++, loops, modulus

this is my first time posting a question, but this loop drove me crazy. I cant figure out what is wrong with it. It crashes at the moment when it enters the second loop. It looks fine and makes sense but still it does not work. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
/**
Author: Yunus Kulyyev
Date: 10-Dec-2016
Description:
**/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int x=1; x < 10; x++)
    {
        cout << x <<": ";
        for (int y = 0; y <= x; y++)
        {
            if (x%y == 0)
            {
            cout << y;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On the first iteration, when `y==0`, what do you expect would be the value of `x % y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second operand of `/` or `%` is zero, then the behavior is **undefined**. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370154/cant-mod-zero) in SO. In your program, for the first iteration of the inner for loop, `y = 0` and thus the following code snippet results in **undefined** behavior.

```
if (x%y == 0) {
    cout << y;
}
```

Comment: @YunusKulyyev best way to thank is accepting the answer :)

Comment: @YunusKulyyev you can accept my answer if it helped you.