# Understanding swift functions

Tags: swift

I'm studying swift and I wonder why following code:

```
func isNumberDivisible(_ number: Int, by divior: Int) -> Bool {

    if number % divior == 0 {
        return true;
    }   else {
        return false;
    }
}

func isPrime (_ number: Int) -> Bool {

    var isPrimeNumber = false

    for index in 0..<number {

        if (isNumberDivisible(number, by:index )) {
            isPrimeNumber = false
        }   else {
            isPrimeNumber = true
        }
    }

    return isPrimeNumber
}

isPrime(10)
```

Output an error - Execution was interrupted, EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION..

Comment: Because you're dividing by zero?

Comment: Are you dividing by zero?

Comment: Which line is causing the issue, with what value?

Comment: @Hamish Hes not dividing. Its a mod `%` operator.  But its throwing error because you are using `%` with zero which is not defined I guess.

Comment: But it does a division first

Comment: @LucasPalaian I just meant it literally with the operator :) Sorry my bad ! But another thing OP: you need to start the loop from 2

Comment: You need `for index in 2..<number`, not `for index in 0..<number`.

Comment: Related ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370154/cant-mod-zero

Comment: @GoodSp33d Technically, `%` is a *remainder* operator in Swift (not modulo), as it just negates the results for a negative dividend. And okay, OP *himself* isn't technically dividing by zero, but he's asking Swift to tell him the remainder when a given number is divided by 0 – which is invalid.

Comment: Note that Xcode comes with a decent *debugger.* If you single-step through the code then you should find the problem quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for loop` starts with zero.  That's a meaningless test, and so is checking if you can divide by 1.

You should start your index at 2

```
for index in 2..<number {
```

and once you find it is NOT a prime number, you should stop - what this function actually prints out is whether or not the number is divisible by (number - 1).  And as @rmaddy points out, you don't need to check every number - in your example 10 is divisible by 2 and 5 - but you don't need to check 5, because you will have already failed on 2

```
for index in 2..<Int(sqrt(Double(number))) {

        if (isNumberDivisible(number, by:index )){
            isPrimeNumber = false
            break
        }   else{
            isPrimeNumber = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: And it should end at the `Int(sqrt(number))`.

Comment: It also is kind of backwards - for a non-prime it will loop more than necessary. The looping/flags should be refactored to improved efficiency asking if 10000 is Prime will loop 10000 times as is, and 10000-2=9998 times if started at 2 or 100 times with @rmaddy correction. If flagged properly, it would loop 1 time.

Answer (score 3):

- The remainder operator (`%`) performs a division
- The first index is 0
- `number % divior` does 10 / 0

Division by zero causes a runtime error.

By the way, the first prime number is 2

```
for index in 2..<number
```

and your *algorithm* doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Doesn't the algorithm work if you put a break in the first if ?

Comment: Looks like homework - they might have been told to follow this approach.  A coding exercise may have different objectives than optimising runtime performance