# Suitable type of function when more than one integer is returned

Tags: c++

How can I have a function in c++ with array returning type ?

For example consider this simple function that calculate divisors of a number, in every step of for loop `i` has an new value .

```
int divisorDeterminer(int num) 
{
    int i = 0 ;

    for (i; i < num; i++) 
    {
        if (num % i == 0) 
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to have divisors as an array  , but I don't know how to ?

Comment: Why not return e.g. a `vector<int>`?

Comment: @pouyan_BN just google `std::vector` , i'm sure this has been asked a million times before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::array` is a thing, if you know how many items it will contain at compile time.
In your case the number of items will vary, so a `std::vector` would work.
There are various containers in the standard library; it's worth reading about them, but `std::vector` is often the go-to data type.

```
std::vector<int> divisorDeterminer(int num) 
{
    std::vector<int> divisors;
    for (int i=1; i < num; i++) //<--- start at 1, not 0
    {
        if (num % i == 0) 
        {
            divisors.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return divisors;
}
```

Edit:
The original code checks from `i=0`, but should 0 count as a divisor of anything? Probably not. It also strays into undefined behaviour (UB), as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370154/cant-mod-zero), so I've started the loop from 1.

Comment: Why divide by `0` ? `i` should be initialized to `1`

Comment: and `i` should end at `num/2`. There won't be a number greater than `num/2` which will divide `num` and leave remainder `0`

Comment: There are optimisations, true. To me, that's a different question. We should be suspicious of a (signed) inttoo - what about negative numbers? Should we return them too?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate from `1` to `num/2` to get the list of all divisors.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
std::vector<int> divisorDeterminer(int num) 
{
   std::vector<int> divisors;
    for (int i=1; i <= num/2 ; i++) 
    {
        if (num % i == 0) 
        {
            divisors.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return divisors;
}
```