# When I run this program I get an error called "Floating point exception"

Tags: c

I get a floating point exception when running this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check(int n)
{
    int ii=0;
    int jj=0;
    int sum_of_dividors=0;
    int sum_of_dividors2=0;
    for (ii=0;ii<n;ii++){
        for (jj=0;jj<ii;jj++){
            if(ii%jj==0)
            {
              sum_of_dividors=sum_of_dividors+jj;
            }
        }
        if(sum_of_dividors<n || ii<n){
            for (jj=0;jj<sum_of_dividors;jj++){
                if(sum_of_dividors%jj==0)
                {
                sum_of_dividors2=sum_of_dividors2+jj;
                }
            }
        if (sum_of_dividors2==ii){
            printf("%d and %d,",ii,sum_of_dividors);
        }
        }
    sum_of_dividors=0;
    sum_of_dividors2=0;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int n;

    printf("Enter n ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%d",check(n));
}
```

The code's purpose is to check the closest pair of amicable numbers to the number (n) that the user have entered.

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: `a % 0` is a tricky thing to evaluate.

Comment: [Can't Mod Zero?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7370154)

Comment: `int check(int n) { [ ..... ] }`  Where is the `return` statement? `check` is supposed to return an `int`, but never returns anything.

Comment: You should've specified **where** that exception occurs. But assuming it was at the attempted modulo, if only everyone would just flag as a dupe of that instead of generating more unnecessary posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C 6.5.5 [ISO/IEC 9899:2011] states:**

> The result of the `/` operator is the quotient from the division of the
>   first operand by the second; the result of the `%` operator is the
>   remainder. **In both operations, if the value of the second operand is
>   zero, the behavior is undefined**.

So, modulo by zero invoked undefined behaviour in C.

Answer (score 1):

If you check with GDB, the problem is in the line

`if(ii%jj==0)`

You [Can't Mod Zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7370154)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `mod % by 0` ! It will give undefined behavior !

Answer (score 0):

You should apply for `%`, apart from the result, exactly the same constraints as `/`. Therefore, in C and C++, you can't mod by 0. If you want to have a behavior where X % 0 equals X, you'll have to check specifically for X to be equal to 0, and return it.