# getting ~ no response on stdout ~ on hackerrank problem

Tags: c++

I wrote the code for a simple problem on HackerRank where you have to count the number of digits of a number which divide the number with 0 remainder.

I used a basic while loop for testing each digit. Number of test cases are t and the number is n.

The code that I wrote is:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    int count[t];
    for (int t_itr = 0; t_itr < t; t_itr++) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        int dig,temp=n;
        count[t_itr]=0;
        while(n>0){
            dig=n%10;
            if(temp%dig==0){
                count[t_itr]++;
            }
            n=n/10;
        }
    }
    for(int x=0;x<t;x++){
        cout<<count[x]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
2
12
1012
```

Expected Output:

```
2
3
```

My Output:

```
~ no response on stdout ~
```

Comment: You should never `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.  It is not proper C++.  It ruins portability and fosters terrible habits.  See [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095).

Comment: Also, please avoid `using namespace std;`.  It is considered bad practice.  See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)

Comment: @L.F. Thanks a lot for sharing this information,

Comment: The declaration `int count[t];` is invalid C++ only as an extension to some compilers.  Please use `std::vector`.  Arrays must have capacities defined at compile time.

Comment: `if (temp % dig == 0)` isn't valid when `dig` is 0. Your program crashes.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for the information. But is this why I'm not getting any output?

Comment: What are the results when you used a debugger?  Which statement is causing the issue?  What are the values of variables used in the statement?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yeah, that was the issue. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Drashti If you used a real compiler, you would have seen the error right away, as [demonstrated here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ec774bd0af37e1e).  Also note the data -- it is hard-coded into the program, which is what you should have done in your code if you're going to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as pointed out by @RetiredNinja, is that [you are invoking undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7370211/10957435):

> The C++ Standard(2003) says in §5.6/4,
>
> > [...] If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined; [...]
>
> That is, following expressions invoke undefined-behavior(UB):
>
> X / 0; //UB
>   X % 0; //UB

[Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), if you're not aware:

> undefined behavior - there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program.

In other words, if your program has Undefined Behavior in it, C++ puts no restrictions on what happens in the program. [Your program can literally do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132574/does-undefined-behavior-really-permit-anything-to-happen), including--but not limited to--not putting anything in `std::cout`.