# why this code does not work only when i provide a number having zero in it ? for example t=1 and string = "1012"

Tags: c++, string

In this question what I have to do is: find the no. of digits in the given string which are divisor of the complete number represented by the string.

For numbers without 0 in it  it is working fine. for example t=1 , s="12" , output=2

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    long long t,i,n,ct;
    cin>>t;

    while(t--)
    {
        ct=0;
        cin>>s;
        n=stoi(s);

        for(i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            if(n%(s[i]-'0') == 0 && s[i] != '0')
            {
                ct++;
            }
        }

        cout<<ct<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the code supposed to do? What is "working fine" and what is "not working" ?

Comment: Have you actually tried to debug your own code? Set breakpoints and go step by step?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370154/cant-mod-zero

Comment: Also don't write `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and don't use `using namespace std;`. Read about it here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice and https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.

Comment: hi , this question is from hackerrank - [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-digits/problem) . The input is integer i know but for practicing and my curiosity purpose only i tried to do it using string. And yes i always debug my code using print statements also. What is not working in this code is if the string is a number having zero in it then `the code stops working on encountering 0 otherwise for the numbers which don't have zero in it , it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
if(n%(s[i]-'0') == 0 && s[i] != '0')
```

For a start, this is in the wrong order. You want to ensure it's not `'0'` *before* attempting a division-type operation. The reason for this is that C++ uses short-circuiting operation so that in the following code, if `xyzzy` is false, `plugh` will never be evaluated:

```cpp
if (xyzzy && plugh)
```

If `xyzzy` is a "dangerous" operation that shouldn't happen when `plugh` is false, you'll get into trouble.

In your specific code, what you have will *first* try to evaluate the division before checking the digit. So, it will allow division by zero to be performed, not really a good idea. It would be safer to use:

```cpp
if ((s[i] != '0') && (n % (s[i] - '0') == 0))
```

---

There's a few other *minor* issues in your code such as signed/unsigned comparisons, or the not-really-necessary use of `long long`<sup>(a)</sup>, or not following the guideline of declaring variables where they're *needed* rather than at some point long before then (such as at the top of the function).

But it's the order of the sub-expressions in the `if` statement that's most likely your immediate issue.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Just how long do you expect these strings to *get?* :-)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! Now it's working fine. I will really take care of the points you told next time. Btw in the original question the input was integer and can be between 0 to 10^9.