# c++ error using std::accumulate creating Least Common Multiple class

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl

I am trying to write a class the calculates the Least Common Multiple:

LeastCommonMultiple.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef LEASTCOMMONMULTIPLE_H
#define LEASTCOMMONMULTIPLE_H

#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

class LeastCommonMultiple
{
public:
    LeastCommonMultiple(std::vector<int>&);

    int GetLcmForVector();

private:
    std::vector<int> &m_list;

    int GetGreatestCommonDivisor(int, int);
    int GetLeastCommonMultiple(int, int);
};
#endif //! LEASTCOMMONMULTIPLE_H
```

LeastCommonMultiple.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LeastCommonMultiple.h"

LeastCommonMultiple::LeastCommonMultiple(std::vector<int>& list) : m_list(list) 
{}

int LeastCommonMultiple::GetGreatestCommonDivisor(int a, int b)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        if (a == 0)
        {
            return b;
        }           

        b %= a;

        if (b == 0) 
        {
            return a;
        }

        a %= b;
    }
}

int LeastCommonMultiple::GetLeastCommonMultiple(int a, int b)
{
    int temp = LeastCommonMultiple::GetGreatestCommonDivisor(a, b);

    return temp ? (a / temp * b) : 0;
}

int LeastCommonMultiple::GetLcmForVector()
{
//std::accumulate takes first, last, initial value, operation
    int result = std::accumulate(m_list.begin(), m_list.end(), 1, LeastCommonMultiple::GetLeastCommonMultiple);

    return result;
}
```

I am getting the error:

> *Error    C3867   'LeastCommonMultiple::GetLeastCommonMultiple': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member   myproject*

Before making this code object Oriented I tested it using the `GetLcmForVector()` function in `main()` and passing `std::accumulate` an array and it worked fine.

**I have read other questions on this error and the issue was forgetting to add parenthesis at the end of the function** BUT I should not have to do that with `LeastCommonMultiple::GetLeastCommonMultiple` since it is being used in `std::accumulate`

I am basing my code off this post:

[C++ algorithm to calculate least common multiple for multiple numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229870/c-algorithm-to-calculate-least-common-multiple-for-multiple-numbers)

Comment: is this really the error you get? There is no `EarliestDeadlineFirstScheduling` in the code

Comment: Sorry, I should have taken that part out of the error. This piece of code is from a bigger project that I am working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) for this:

```
int result = std::accumulate(m_list.begin(), m_list.end(), 1, 
             std::bind(
                 &LeastCommonMultiple::GetLeastCommonMultiple, 
                 this, 
                 std::placeholders::_1, 
                 std::placeholders::_2
             ));
```

This "binds" the member function you are trying to use with the current object. (The `std::placeholder::_X` represents one of the parameters of the function you are trying to pass)

On the other hand, you could make the method you are trying to use `static` and use `&` when passing it to `std::accumulate`.

Finally, you could even use a lambda here! <sub>Thanks to @Jarod42 for this</sub>

```
int result = std::accumulate(m_list.begin(), m_list.end(), 1, 
            [this](int acc, int v) 
            { 
                return GetLeastCommonMultiple(acc, v); 
            });
```

On a side note, for this line of code:

```
int temp = LeastCommonMultiple::GetGreatestCommonDivisor(a, b);
```

You don't need the class name mentioned with the member function since it is not static.

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer and introducing me to std::bind, worked perfect!

Answer (score 3):

As state in error message: missing `&`:

```
std::accumulate(m_list.begin(),
                m_list.end(),
                1,
                &LeastCommonMultiple::GetLeastCommonMultiple);
```

In addition the method should be `static`.

Regular free functions don't requires `&` due to heritage of `C` :/

Comment: I'd make `GetLeastCommonMultiple` a free function rather than a static, and also make `LeastCommonMultiple` a namespace

Comment: I didn't realize I had to pass the function as reference to std::accumulate, thank you for clarifying the actual error message for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could make LeastCommonMultiple a static method since it uses no state.

```
    int static GetLeastCommonMultiple(int a, int b);
    int static GetGreatestCommonDivisor(int a, int b);
```

...

```
    int result = std::accumulate(m_list.begin(), m_list.end(), 1, 
                                 &LeastCommonMultiple::GetLeastCommonMultiple);
```